# jQuery UI Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have this bootstrap3 modal structure in my project and I want to have modal resizable and dragable.
I found **[this example](http://addyosmani.github.io/jquery-ui-bootstrap/components.html#dialog)** which use jQuery ui to do that, but when I have applied  this function from example into my project is not working :|

```
// Modal Link
$('#modal_link').click(function () {
    $('#dialog-message').dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

```
<div style="display: none;" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div id="dialog" class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

if someone can help me with this situation pls.
**[Here is a fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/GpdgF/235/)**
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a div with an id of "dialog-message" in your code snippet.  Should your outer div include id="dialog-message"?